# not able to create separate log files according to the levels with the xml in log4j

Tags: java, xml, logging, jboss, log4j

I am trying to create a small application using log4j in Struts 2. I want to create different log files for different levels. 
But what I got is a LOG FILE with all messages in one.

Following is the XML of my project -

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE log4j:configuration SYSTEM "log4j.dtd">
<log4j:configuration xmlns:log4j="http://jakarta.apache.org/log4j/" debug="false">
<appender name="FTP" class="org.jboss.logging.appender.DailyRollingFileAppender">
      <errorHandler class="org.jboss.logging.util.OnlyOnceErrorHandler"/>
      <param name="File" value="/home/stpl/Desktop/jboss-4.2.2.GA_new  /server/default/ftp.log"/>
      <param name="Append" value="true"/>
      <param name="DatePattern" value="'.'yyyy-MM-dd"/>
      <layout class="org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout">         
       <param name="ConversionPattern" value="%d   %5p   [%c] %t  %x %m%n"/>     
      </layout>
      <filter class="org.apache.log4j.filter.LevelRangeFilter">
          <param name="LevelMin" value="DEBUG"/>
          <param name="LevelMax" value="FATAL"/>
        </filter>
   </appender>
   <!--messages to the console-->

   <appender name="CONSOLE" class="org.apache.log4j.ConsoleAppender">
      <errorHandler class="org.jboss.logging.util.OnlyOnceErrorHandler"/>
      <param name="Target" `enter code here`value="System.out"/>
      <param name="Threshold" value="DEBUG"/>
      <layout class="org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout">
         <!-- The default pattern: Date Priority [Category] Message\n -->
         <param name="ConversionPattern" value="%d{ABSOLUTE} %-5p [%c{1}] %m%n"/>
      </layout>
   </appender>
   
   <logger name="com.opensymphony.xwork2">
    <level value="INFO" />
    <appender-ref ref="fileAppenderInfo" />
    <appender-ref ref="consoleAppenderInfo" />
    </logger>
     
    <logger name="org.apache.struts2">
    <level value="INFO" />
    <appender-ref ref="fileAppenderInfo" />
    <appender-ref ref="consoleAppenderInfo" />
     </logger>

     <root>
          <appender-ref ref="CONSOLE"/>
          <appender-ref ref="FTP"/>
      </root>

</log4j:configuration>
```

Comment: In orderd to have multiple files, you are gona need to create multiple file appenders. Currently you have ove file appender and three loggers.

Comment: how will i set the levels for that particular file in the apender?

Comment: and there is one more problem. when i clear the log file and run my project then there is no log message is added to  that file.

Answer (score 0):

Enable logging on minimum desired level (trace, debug). Use multiple file appenders. Use threshold filter on each appender to filter lower level events.

```
<log4j:configuration xmlns:log4j="http://jakarta.apache.org/log4j/">
    <appender name="debugAppender" class="org.apache.log4j.FileAppender"> 
        <param name="File" value="/logs/debug.log"/> 
        <param name="Threshold" value="debug"/> 
        <layout class="org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout"> 
            <param name="ConversionPattern" value="%d{ABSOLUTE} %-5p %c{1} : %m%n"/> 
        </layout> 
    </appender> 

    <appender name="errorAppender" class="org.apache.log4j.FileAppender"> 
        <param name="File" value="/logs/error.log"/> 
        <param name="Threshold" value="error"/> 
        <layout class="org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout"> 
            <param name="ConversionPattern" value="%d{ABSOLUTE} %-5p %c{1} : %m%n"/> 
        </layout> 
    </appender> 

    <root> 
        <level value="debug"/> 
        <appender-ref ref="errorAppender" /> 
        <appender-ref ref="debugAppender" /> 
    </root> 
</log4j:configuration>
```

This way debug appender logs everything from root logger, while errorAppender logs everything on error level or higher.

Now this will not filter out error events from debug log, but you can always use [DynamicThresholdFilter](https://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.0/manual/filters.html#DynamicThresholdFilter) for even more complex filtering.

Comment: Nothing is happening by using the above code. There is no data updated on any file. Although i have used consoleAppender too but there is no message  shown on the consol.

Comment: My log.xml file is placed under scr folder. But i think it should be written in the /jboss-log4j.xml file.

Comment: This will work when i Configure my project with jboss-log4j.xml file. and with this the logs are separated by the levels. But when i write the xml file in src folder then it will not Configured with my project.